# How can I use react-draft-wysiwyg module in React 18.2.0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, version, vite, react-draft-wysiwyg

Recently, I am building forum page for my customer’s project and I use vite for this project.

I am going to use Editor from react-draft-wysiwyg module.

I have already been used this module before but react version was 16.8 atm.

For this project, I was going to install this module in React 18.2.0 but it wasn’t installed so I used this command:

```
npm install react-draft-wysiwyg — legacy-peer-deps
```

By this command I installed this module successfully but I can’t import from this module.

How can I resolve this issue?